# I cant make a dynamic image path in pdf

Tags: image, pdf, dynamic, fpdf, display

I've been trying to display an image in a fpdf file, it only works when I specify the exact location of the image. Can I make it dynamic?

Heres sample line of code:

```
$this->Image('fpdf/img/logo1.png',10,6,30);
```

and it works when I turn this way:

> D:\Installed Apps\New
>   folder\XAMPP\htdocs\votingsystem\application\views\admin\senior\fpdf\img\logo1.png',10,6,30);

I want to transfer it to another laptop, I'm afraid it wont work.
I always get this error:

> Message: fopen(fpdf/img/logo1.png): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

I use code igniter as framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multicell option in fpdf. I use this below code in php to it working.

`

```
define('ASSETS_URL','Your url or path to image file');
$yaxix = $pdf->GetY();
$xaxix = $pdf->GetX();
$pdf->MultiCell(50,10.5,$pdf->Image(ASSETS_URL.'/img/your-image-name.jpg',$xaxix,$yaxix+5,50)."\nAuthorised Signatory",1,'C',FALSE);
```

`

In this case you only have to change constants.